# Finding substring when reading from an uploaded file fails

Tags: php, string, file-get-contents, strpos

Why can't I do a proper `strpos` function on an uploaded file (I first upload the file, and then do a `$site = stream_get_line($f, 4096, "\n")`) and it works completely fine when read the same thing into $site from a manually created file on the server.

I have no idea what's causing it... it seems to read the line well in both cases, but `strpos` just doesn't work the same when it's uploaded via user versus when I create it manually.

Here's the code:

```php
<?php
if(!$_FILES){ 
?>

<head>
<title>Bulk Index Checker</title>
</head>
    <center>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Check 'em!" />
        </form>
    </center>

<?php
}
else{

    echo("<center> <h1>Checking... please wait.</h1> <br><table border=1> <tr><td>Site</td><td>Indexed</td></tr>");
    $target_path = "checkupload/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['file']['name']); 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path);  

    $f = fopen($target_path, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

    while (!feof($f))
    {
        $site = stream_get_line($f, 4096, "\n");
        $url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=info:' . $site;

        //sleep(3);

        $contents = file_get_contents($url);

        if (strpos($contents,'<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q='.$site)!=FALSE) {
            echo("<tr bgcolor=\"Silver\"><td><a href=\"".$url."\" target=\"_blank\">".$site."</a></td><td>YES</td></tr>");
            echo("<br>");
        }
        else{
            echo("<tr><td><a href=\"".$url."\" target=\"_blank\">".$site."</a></td><td>NO</td></tr>");
        }
    }
?>

</table>
<br/>
<form>
</center>

<?php
}
?>
```

Edit: Here's another way I tried (using textarea) - same thing basically - it ONLY works properly when you input only 1 URL. As soon as you input another URL below, it shows a FALSE for the first one when it's really TRUE.

WHY IS THIS HAPPENING?

```
<?php
if(!$_POST){ 
?>

<head>
<title>Bulk Index Checker</title>
</head>
    <center>
        <h1>Bulk Index Checker v1.0</h1>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <textarea id="list" name="list" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Check 'em!" />
        </form>
    </center>

<?php
}
else{
    echo("<center> <h1>Checking... please wait.</h1> <br><table border=1> <tr><td>Site</td><td>Indexed</td></tr>");

    $lines = explode("\n", $_POST['list']);

    foreach($lines as $site) {
        echo($site);
        $url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=info:' . $site;

        sleep(3);

        $contents = file_get_contents($url);

        if (strpos($contents,'<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q='.$site)!=FALSE) {
            echo("<tr bgcolor=\"Silver\"><td><a href=\"".$url."\" target=\"_blank\">".$site."</a></td><td>YES</td></tr>");
            echo("<br>");
        }
        else{
            echo("<tr><td><a href=\"".$url."\" target=\"_blank\">".$site."</a></td><td>NO</td></tr>");
        }
    }
?>

</table>
<br/>
</center>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Rethorical question: Have you checked the return value of `move_uploaded_file`?

Comment: nope, i just used that piece of code from the net, it was the first thing that came up for uploading text files via php

Comment: Unfortunately, I found that the first answer to about any PHP question I had always turned out to be wrong. ;) And I'm not even kidding. Nevertheless. Apparently the moving has gone wrong, but that could have various reasons, one of them being that the script has no file write access to that directory. Hard to tell the exact reason, so make sure to check every part of your script for functions that may return useful error information.

Comment: Its so weird because when I only put 1 URL in the file, it checks out alright, returns proper result. But when I add another URL to the file (below the existing one), thats when it starts acting weird and even returns opposite result for the first URL than it did when it was the only one inside the file. I tried the same thing using textarea instead of file uploading - SAME THING!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use '!==' instead of '!='.

I don't have an option to test at this stage. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php (example #2)